# Get a line number on Powershell?

Tags: powershell

So I have been searching a lot and couldn't find anything that wouldn't return me nothing.

I have a code with a variable and I have a file with a lot of lines on it.
For example, I have the following file (things.txt):

*Ketchup*

*Mustard*

*Pumpkin*

*Mustard*

*Ketchup*

And what I want to take out is the line numbers of "Mustard". Here's the code I'm trying right now

```
$search="Mustard"
$linenumber=Get-Content things.txt | select-string $search -context 0,1
$linenumber.context
```

But it actually returns "". Everyone online was about using context but I only want to know the line number of every "Mustard" which are 2 and 4.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `Select-String $search things.txt | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LineNumber`

Comment: @Bill_Stewart that returns me nothing too... Also "Get-Content things.txt | Select-String $search | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LineNumber " more of the same

Comment: Sorry; can't reproduce. Just tested and it works fine for me.

Comment: `(sls $search things.txt).Linenumber`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Select-String` returns the line number for you.  You're just looking at the wrong property.  Change your code to:

```
$search="Mustard"
$linenumber= Get-Content thing.txt | select-string $search
$linenumber.LineNumber
```

Comment: Returns me nothing... I'm starting to think there is something wrong with the program itself...

Comment: Works fine for me.  Is there more going on in your real script than your example?  Does running just `Get-Content thing.txt | select-string "Mustard"` produce any output?

Comment: Yeah it returns me all the "Mustard"

Comment: Anything from this?  `(Get-Content thing.txt | select-string "Mustard").LineNumber`

Comment: absolutely nothing... I'm about just to make another file, I can't believe it doesn't work whatever I do

Comment: So alright I found the problem. It was a bad var, just had the wrong name all along lol thank you very much!!

Comment: Try my example again (first comment on your question - shorter and more direct way).

Comment: Is it possible to have `more` with line numbers?

Answer (score 5):

For people who are searching for one liner, code is self explanatory.

```
Get-Content .\myTextFile.txt | Select-String -Pattern "IamSearching" | Select-Object LineNumber
```

*Edit(April 2022):*

OR

```
(Select-String .\myTextFile.txt -Pattern "IamSearching").LineNumber
```

Comment: Nice, though you probably want `Select-Object -ExpandProperty LineNumber` if only the numbers should be reported.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give a practical example of usage.

Here is an example together with Docker logs. I have running a Docker container with container id starting with 42. I want to see why the Docker container fails at start. It tries to connect to Mongoose DB and container fails. I redirect the output and I use select-string to achieve this.

First I run this command :

```
docker logs 42 2>&1 | select-string -pattern "Error" | select LineNumber,Line
```

This then gives me both the LineNumber and the Line, so I can see where in the output I have the pattern with text "Error".

You can use this on similar streams such as strings and files that are string based in Powershell.

Answer (score -1):

Try insert `-Path` after `Get-Content`