# How to Access Powershell Select-String Return Values

Tags: powershell, text

I have a header section at the beginning of a text file `test.txt`:

```
BLOGS-BODGER
SMALLTOWN COMPOSITE ROLL
PAGE 6
PAGE 7
SMALLTOWN COMPOSITE ROLL
BOOMER-BYGRAVE
```

I am extracting data from this header in the following way:

```
$filesPathText = "C:\test\test3\test.txt"

# find NAME-NAME strings in text file test.txt
$names = Select-String -Path $filesPathText -Pattern '[A-Z]-[A-Z]'
Write-Host "First name" $names[0] "Second name" $names[1]

# find PAGE X strings in text file test.txt
$pages = Select-String -Path $filesPathText -Pattern 'PAGE'
Write-Host "First page" $pages[0] "Second page" $pages[1]
```

The output is the following:

```
First name C:\test\test3\test.txt:3:BLOGS-BODGER Second name C:\test\test3\test.txt:8:BOOMER-BYGRAVE
First page C:\test\test3\test.txt:5:PAGE 6 Second page C:\test\test3\test.txt:6:PAGE 7
```

I can access line numbers in the following way:

```
[int]$lineNum = $names[1].LineNumber
```

So how do I do something similar for the NAME & PAGE values. That is to assign NAME & PAGE data to a variable by eliminating the path & line number data?

This doc is close [Example 3: Find a pattern match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.2) but doesn't go into parsing out individual elements. This SO post [Get a line number on Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044959/get-a-line-number-on-powershell) has a references to piping output to `Select-Object` & Expanding Properties??

Any suggestions/explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you're looking for the `.Line` property of the returned object

Comment: No. I have said that I have found the `.Line` property. I'm looking for something like a `.Pattern` property. A property that is NOT line or path. I have tried various property options from VS Code Powershell extension/IntelliSense but nothing works. I think if the data is in the output then there must be a way of accessing it.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your question having mentioned the `.Line` property you have mentioned `.LineNumber`.

Comment: is the real data so ... badly sequenced? it seems to be `name, location, page` and then `page, location, name` . that is horribly difficult to parse since it has no regular structure.

Comment: Is `BOOMER-BYGRAVE` the start of a new section (new name?) or is it that all one entry?  Can you provide a bigger sample?

Comment: My apologies @Santiago Squarzon You are correct. I am confusing `.Line` with `.LineNumber` If you had provided this as an answer with explanation I could have upvoted. Thank you

Comment: @Lee_Dailey my test script is modelling a header from OCR generated text files. Yes the data is badly sequenced. Not only is it badly sequenced it also has many errors because the original images are of old (1981) typewritten Electoral Rolls. Unfortunately I have to make the best of what I've got.

Comment: @Daniel The original files are JPG images of old telephone book type entries. The image is of an open book (two pages) Each page has 200 entries of SURNAME, first names, address & occupation. At the top of the page there is the header NAME-NAME range, the roll description BLAH COMPOSITE ROLL & the PAGE X. When the image is run through an OCR process it throws the text together. The top line header is then represented as in my example. This is just a small step along the way to outputting complete formatted listings.

Comment: @Dave - thank you for the clarification. [*grin*] ///// you may want to look into the following cmdlets >>> `Get-Command convertfrom-string*` <<<

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) has provided the crucial pointer in a comment:

- To obtain the *line text* from a [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instance that [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) outputs for each match, access its **`.Line`** property.

  - Note: If you're *only* looking for the line text, PowerShell (Core) 7+ offers a simpler solution, namely the **`-Raw`** switch.
  - The property name *Line* can be misleading, because, strictly speaking, it is the entire text of the matching input string, which, depending on how input is provided, may itself be composed of *multiple* lines.<sup>[1]</sup>
- To obtain *which search pattern matched* - which is only of interest if *multiple* patterns were passed - use the **`.Pattern`** property.
- To obtain only the *matching part* of a line, i.e. the part that matched the search pattern, use **`.Matches.Value`** (or, more strictly, `.Matches[0].Value`).

  - Note: `.Matches` is an *array* of [`[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match) instances, but that array only ever contains *multiple* elements if `-AllMatches` was also specified, in order to request potentially *multiple* matches *per line* (per input object).
  - If your search regex(es) contain *capture groups* (subexpressions enclosed in `(...)`), you can access what they captured via the `.Matches[0].Groups` property.<sup>[2]</sup>

To illustrate all three; note that regex `pag.` is used to (case-insensitively) match verbatim string `PAGE`, to illustrate the difference between `.Pattern` and `.Matches.Value`; also, the values are enclosed in `[...]` for delineation:

```
'PAGE 6' | Select-String -Pattern pag. | ForEach-Object {
  [pscustomobject] @{
    Line = '[{0}]' -f $_.Line
    Pattern = '[{0}]' -f $_.Pattern    
    MatchingLinePart = '[{0}]' -f $_.Matches.Value
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Line     Pattern MatchingLinePart
----     ------- ----------------
[PAGE 6] [pag.]  [PAGE]
```

---

<sup>[1] E.g. `` ("a`nb" | Select-String a).Line `` outputs the full two-line input string, because it was provided as a single input object.</sup>

<sup>[2] E.g, `'PAGE 6' | Select-String 'page (\d+)' | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value }` outputs string `6`; index `1` refers to the first (and only) capture group (`(...)`) in the regex.</sup>

---

**Discovering a cmdlet's output data type**:

- **Via [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member)**:

  - Pipe a concrete call to `Get-Member` to discover that call's output type and its members; add `-Type Properties` to limit the display of members; e.g.:

    ```
    PS> 'foo' | Select-String foo | Get-Member -Type Properties 

        TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo

     Name       MemberType Definition
     ----       ---------- ----------
     Context    Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfoContext Context {get;set;}
     Filename   Property   string Filename {get;}
     IgnoreCase Property   bool IgnoreCase {get;set;}
     Line       Property   string Line {get;set;}
     LineNumber Property   int LineNumber {get;set;}
     Matches    Property   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[] Matches {get;set;}
     Path       Property   string Path {get;set;}
     Pattern    Property   string Pattern {get;set;}
    ```
- **Via a cmdlet's documentation**: A cmdlet's help contains an [`OUTPUTS` section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string#outputs) that describes the .NET data type(s) of the objects output by that cmdlet.

  - To see this section *locally*, you must invoke [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help) with the `-Full` switch, e.g. `Get-Help Select-String -Full`

    - `-Full` results in lengthy output in which the `OUTPUTS` section may get buried; to isolate it, use something like the following:

      ```
      (Get-Help Select-String -Full | Out-String) -replace '(?sm).+^(OUTPUTS.+?)^\S.+$', '$1'
      ```
  - Note that a given cmdlet may situationally produce *different* output types; e.g., with the `-Quiet` switch `Select-String` emits a Boolean.